# MongoDB Performance vs Relational DB for Many-Many One-Many

Tags: mongodb, relational-database, database

Let's say I have a many-to-many relationship between Students and Teachers and I build an app for this where I assign students to teachers, and teachers to students. I'd probably want my data normalized (I'd have a Teacher Collection and a Student Collection).

I'm wondering, in the above case (many-to-many) would the performance be better if I were to use a relational database (such as MySQL) instead of MongoDb? And how about the performance for One-to-many?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, depends on implementation. In MySql it depends on how you lay out the schema and index it.

Flat DB storage (Mongo) does not mean you will automatically gain performance. It's purely subjective.

Here is an example in MySql based on your description.

```
create table teachers (teacher_id int Primary Key, teacher_name varchar(20))
create table students (student_id int Primary Key, student_name varchar(20))
create table teacher_student_assoc (assoc_id int Primary Key, teacher_id int, student_id int) create index on teacher_id and student_id
```

Unless your MySql db is going to get hammered on (assuming your site gets 100K hits a day) I don't see the reason why you need to worry about performance.

You can also implement memcacheif need be.

Good luck.